# Flask Python. Consulta MySQL. Traer toda la estructura de la tabla con sus resultados

Tags: python, mysql, flask

Estoy usando Flask para hacer una API, estoy utilizando:
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

Para dicho fin. Bien, esto es el código de una consulta que estoy haciendo por SP:

```
                                        respuesta=cursor.execute("CALL SP_Ver_Datos_Lista()")    
                                        respuesta=cursor.fetchall()
                                        print (respuesta)
                                        cursor.close()
                                        return jsonify(respuesta), 200
```

Funciona la consulta:

```
    ((1, 'dato'), (2, 'dato'), (3, 'dato'), (4, 'dato'), (5, 'dato'), (6, 'dato'), (7, 'dato'), (8, 'dato'))
```

Bien. Lo que no entiendo, es ¿Por qué trae solo los datos y no la estructura de la tabla?, es decir, algo así:

```
    ((id:1, nombre:'dato'), (id:2, nombre:'dato'), (id:3, nombre:'dato'), (id:4, nombre:'dato'), (id:5, nombre:'dato'), id:(6, nombre:'dato'), (id:7, nombre:'dato'), (id:8, nombre:'dato'))
```

¿Qué puedo usar para traer campos con los datos?

Gracias y saludos.

Comment: Es imposible traer los datos en la forma que quieres, puesto que el resultado es una tupla (en concreto una tupla de tuplas) donde solo hay valores, no claves.  Si quieres  "conservar" mejor la estructura deberás hacerlo manualmente, una opción sería iterar en el resultado y crear un diccionario o una lista de diccionarios para tener los datos como tu quieres. Pero una opción más sencilla es usar un ORM, por ejemplo [`peewee`](https://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/)

Comment: ¿Tienes algún ejemplo de cómo hacer "manualmente"  y de cómo crear dicho diccionario?. Gracias, Christian por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma sencilla de asemejarnos al resultado que buscas puede ser mediante la creación de una lista de diccionarios (o una tupla si así lo deseas)

Para este caso ya tendré la respuesta en una variable para hacer la prueba.

```py
res = ((1, 'dato'), (2, 'dato'), (3, 'dato'), (4, 'dato'), (5, 'dato'), (6, 'dato'), (7, 'dato'), (8, 'dato'))
```

Como mencioné en mi comentario no es posible hacer exactamente lo que quieres, es decir tener esto `(id:1, nombre:'dato')`. Eso ya se asemeja más a un diccionario, por lo cual en mi ejemplo convertiremos la tupla a un diccionario.

La función es bastante sencilla. Consta en solo recorrer el resultado, acceder a cada elemento de la tupla y crear un diccionario con eso. A continuación muestro un ejemplo usando *list comprehension*

```py
def parse_result(data:tuple[tuple]) -> list[dict]:
    return [{"id": id_, "nombre": nombre} for id_, nombre in data]

res_parse = parse_result(res)
print(res_parse)
```

Teniendo como resultado:

```
[{'id': 1, 'nombre': 'dato'},
 {'id': 2, 'nombre': 'dato'},
 {'id': 3, 'nombre': 'dato'},
 {'id': 4, 'nombre': 'dato'},
 {'id': 5, 'nombre': 'dato'},
 {'id': 6, 'nombre': 'dato'},
 {'id': 7, 'nombre': 'dato'},
 {'id': 8, 'nombre': 'dato'}]
```

Si aún no te familiarizas o te resulta complicado la *list comprehension* puedes optar por un ciclo `for` tradicional.

```py
def parse_result(data:tuple[tuple]) -> list[dict]:
    resultado = []
    for id_, nombre in data:
        resultado.append({"id": id_, "nombre":nombre})
    return resultado
```

**Nota: uso como variable `id_` ya que `id` es una built-in function. Así evito confusiones**

Como recomendación te diría que uses algún ORM, ya sea [peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/), [Sql Alchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) o algún otro ya que te ayudará bastante y tendrás todo más ordenado. Si tienes alguna otra duda la puedes dejar en los comentarios :D

Comment: Gracias, Christian por tu respuesta y ejemplo (tengo 4 días en Flask) porque francamente Django se me hace muy complejo para mí. Voy a intentar implementar lo que mencionas. Sobre el ORM de momento no lo estoy pensando porque primerno no lo se y segundo tengo ya todos los SP´s listos en la BD.

Comment: DJango es para proyectos más complejos y grandes, en mi caso siempre uso Flask. Sobre el ORM de verdad que te ayuda. Tendrás todo más ordenado y separado por clases. Investiga un poco para que veas como va la cosa, si te animas lo implementas, sino tenlo previsto para tu próximo proyecto ^_^